# I want to implement singleton using DI and Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, singleton

Recently I was asked by interviewer on how to implement Singleton using DI and unity framework. I searched in net and I had no codes/directions on this but just the Singleton using static variables I found.

Please help me with a very small understandable code on how to implement Singleton using DI and Unity Framework.

Also, I would like to understand the pros and cons of both these approaches of DI as well as Static variable using property.

Comment: Looking for `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Sorry no clue what you talking about :S